# How to organize directories and files for nested class

Tags: ruby, nested-class

I have classes like this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

class Shelf
  def initialize
    @books = {}
  end
  def book(code: code)
    @books[code] if @books.has_key?(code)
    @books = Book.new(code: code)
  end
end

class Shelf::Book
  def initialize(code: code)
    @code = code
  end
end
```

It works fine, if I write it in a file.

I want to separate classes into two files `shelf.rb` and `shelf/book.rb`, but when I write `require_relative 'shelf/book'` in `shelf.rb` then it fails because `class Shelf` is not defined yet.

How should I organize files and directories?
Or am I using nested class in completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write another file which does not contain class definitions but which will be used tu run your program/script.

At the top of this file

```
require_relative 'shelf'
require_relative 'shelf/book'

#more code instructions
```

You don't need to `require 'shelf/book'` in shelf.rb

Answer (score 2):

[Read this](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/) for naming convention of an `*.rb` file. According to it if you have a class `Shelf`:

```
class Shelf
end
```

then your file name should be `shelf.rb`, and if you have a class named: `Shelf::Book`, then file name `book.rb` should be within *shelf* directory(of course this is not a constraint or mandatory to have it in *shelf* directory, but it's a good convention to follow since any other developer would be able to locate your file *book.rb* easily):

```
class Shelf::Book
end
```

But, your problem is that how you require `Shelf::Book`, in `Shelf`, for that you need to call `require_relative 'shelf/book'` inside `Shelf` class definition, since Ruby will not know about `Shelf` being a class prior to it. Like this:

```
class Shelf
  require_relative 'shelf/book'
end
```

However, if you don't want `Shelf` class's definition to throw error irrespective of where you use line: `require_relative 'shelf/book'` then change you `shelf/book.rb` to something like this:

```
class Shelf
  class Book
    def initialize(code: code)
      @code = code
    end
  end
end
```

Because here Ruby opens up/create a class `Shelf` and won't throw this error:

> `': uninitialized constant Shelf (NameError)

Comment: “if you have a class named: Shelf::Book, then file name book.rb should be **within shelf directory**” Are you sure? From one of their example on the rubygem website you link to `require 'rdoc/data'` Main Class or module RDoc::Data it does not seem the case

Comment: @AurélienBottazini : Of course it's not a constraint, it's more of considered as a good practice to use the convention.

Comment: @AurélienBottazini : Also, read what OP is asking: *How should I organize files and directories? Or am I using nested class in completely wrong way?*. Question clearly ask about organizing file and directory and I don't see reason to not to mention that point in answer.

Comment: here is what I mean. In their example data.rb defining `RDoc::Data` is in rdoc/data directory and not rdoc directory

Comment: @AurélienBottazini : [See it yourself](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc-data/blob/master/lib/rdoc/data.rb), it's inside `rdoc` directory: `rdoc/data.rb`.

Comment: I think you see my comments like negative feedbacks. That is not the case. I did not flag or downvote your answer neither did I told you not to speak about file organisation. I just asked “are you sure?”

Comment: Oh, buddy, not at all. I didn't see your comment as a negative feedback or of any sort, I appreciate that you came forward and asked for a clarification instead. Actually, that's a convention. That's why I used **should**, not **must**. You can have book.rb at `library/book.rb` and then say `require_relative 'library/book'` in `Shelf` class but that breaks the convention and creates difficulties for other to understand and read your code. Which you should definitely consider avoiding while organizing your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64220/discussion-between-aurelien-bottazini-and-user089247).